# How do mail trackers make the original email different for the recipient and the sender?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, tracking

I was exploring the [mailtrack.io](https://mailtrack.io/en/) mail tracker for Gmail, which attaches an image at the end to track emails.

There was a difference in the original HTML source code of the message for the sender and the receiver, ensuring the mail tracker does not get triggered when the sender himself opens the email. This is what the tracker does:

**Sender**

```html
<img width="0" height="0" alt="" style="display:flex" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
```

**Receiver**

```html
<img width="0" height="0" alt="" style="display:flex" src="https://mailtrack.io/trace/mail/random-token.png?u=random">
```

For the sender, the tracker pixel image is encoded in **Base64** form, and the original tracking link is sent only to the receiver.

How can a mail tracker do this if I send the email using a typical Gmail web client? I know that a copy of the email is saved in the sent folder via IMAP, which is definitely handled internally by Gmail and can't be modified by the mail tracker. But in this case, the mail tracker has modified the **original** email content.

Answer (score 1):

It's a browser extension. It can intercept the HTTP response when you load the sent item and rewrite it before it gets to the Gmail web app's JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean the original message still contains the "tracking" link, but it is re-written on the sender's end through the extension?

Comment: @AshishKumar — If that extension works the way I suggested, yes. I'm not going to install the extension and check for you though.

Comment: I uninstalled the extension, still, the link shows in Base64 encoded format. Moreover, I viewed the HTML using the "Show original" option of Gmail, which should not be intercepted by an extension.

Comment: Note that you did ask how a tracker **could** get the desired effect and not how that particular one does (which would be off-topic as you didn't include any debugging information and the question would depend on an external resource to be understood).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, I'm particularly asking, how can a mail tracker change the "original content" of email on the sender and receiver side, not through some client-side interceptions (as these interceptions can't change the original HTML content of the email).